SSRS Reports load for some, but not for others
Last week everything was working fine, but this week some users can no longer run reports on our reporting services, whereas other users can. Permissions haven't changed, the report haven't changed, locations haven't changed. Everyone can still see the report in question, however when they go to run the report it is stuck on the loading screen indefinitely.
Loading Image
What I don't understand is why some users can run it, but some no longer can, and as far as I'm aware nothing has changed.
I have no idea where to start in trying to troubleshoot this issue. No error pops up as it loads forever.
Below are two rows in my report servers Execution Log, the top being a user that can't run the report and the bottom being a user that can. It has always been a rather slow report but ran after about 3 minutes or so, but now some people can't run it at all!


Use report execution log on the reporting services database to see if TimeDataRetrieval is high. If it is high, you have to examine query execution plans (use Query Store if you use SQL Server), compare them to find why some of them are slow (missing indexes, outdated statistics, etc...) and make proper optimizations

This often happens with later versions of chromium based browsers for some reason (Chrome, Brave, new Edge etc..) Try clearing the browser cache (Shift+Ctrl+Del), then closing and reopening the browser.

@niktrs I have attached a screenshot in the question showing rows from my report servers Execution Log. It is two separate users running the same report, from the same location, with the exact same permissions. It just seems that for one use they managed to process and render the report, whereas the other user didn't get past the Data Retrieval stage. I understand that it may be a query issue, I'll look into this now, but do you know why it would behave differently for different users?

@AlanSchofield I tried this but users are still unable to run the report, thank you for the suggestion though.

@Evie you have to compare execution plans, parameters etc. to see why the aborted query runs so slow. Even for the user thats executing, 200 seconds are probably too much execution time
